# eclipse sees make but says it does not

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cygwin

I'm very confused about the error message I get. If I change the path to look for make in "C:\cygwin6400\bin" ( **intentional forcing an error** ) I get 
Cannot run program "make": The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\cygwin6400\bin;......

as I would expect, now if I fix my path to point to "C:\cygwin64\bin" I get

"C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe" all 
Cannot run program "C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe": The system cannot find the file specified.

So what does this error mean then because its not the same error about a missing make file path.

I know its not a path issue as I can run make from a cmd prompt at any location and it runs the make in my cygwin64\bin dir. So my only guess is it cant find something other then make.exe.

Comment: Also if I run make all from the cmd prompt at my source directory it tries to processes the make.

Answer (score 0):

edit the path enviroment variable in your Mycomputer properties and append this line with a semi colon as value for the variable 'path'

```
variable Name:  path

variable value: C:\cygwin64\bin;
```

open a new cmd window and type make, so that you can run make utility.if you run this utility successfully, eclipse ide will recognize the make utility.

Comment: This was addressed in my original post. Please reread it and you will see I tested my path. By removing "C:\cygwin64\bin" from my path I get another type of error.